# java socket server communication easy

Tags: java, sockets, server, communication

Hi i want to program a simple code:
Server and Socket

Server - starts
Socket - want to connect
Servers - accept it

server - waits for a command from the socket
socket - writes a command to the stream
server - wants to respond on the stream

ajsiodjasodasodsa
doesnt work?!

**this ist the socket that connects to the server**

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);) {
        // get the outputstream to write a command to the server as soon as it is
        // connected:
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        // this is the command
        bufferedWriter.write("LISTPARTS");
        bufferedWriter.flush();

        // Now it should open a input stream to read the resonse of the server!
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        System.out.println("\nafter creating the reader");

        String readLine;
        while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) == null) {
            System.out.println("what:" + readLine);
        }
```

**This ist the Server:**

```
   while (true) {
            try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);) {

                System.out.println("wait for Client");
                Socket socket = server.accept(); // wartet bis akzeptiert
                System.out.println("Client was accepted");
                // Open input stream because server waits for a command:
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                // wait for command
                System.out.println("wait for command");
                String readLine;
                while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) == null) {
                    System.out.println("wait for client");
                }
                System.out.println("read line:" + readLine);

                // here it should look if the command works ( this works fine  )
                if (readLine.equals("LISTPARTS")) {

                    System.out.println("Commando: listparts");
                    // for responding the server opens a writer to write the response!
                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                    // this method write onto the stream ( it should work normaly !)
                    circuit.dumpParts(bufferedWriter);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

this is the result of the servers main ouput on the console:

```
Server- Main
wait for Client
Client was accepted
wait for command
```

and that of the sockets console :

```
after creating the reader
```

Comment: `bufferedWriter.write("LISTPARTS\n");` should help

Comment: Please don't add answers to your question unless they actually are answers.  If you have new information to add, just edit the question to include updates and/or new information (Click the edit button, just below the tags).  If you've got a new question, just ask another question, and reference this one if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution:

```
while ((readLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (readLine.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("what:" + readLine);

            }
```